# Windows Folder Security when sharing through a website

Tags: .net, windows, security, filesystems

I'm working on an application that serves up files (e-commerce downloadable content.) The content is stored on a windows folder share on the server and the application then provides access to that content when the uses requests it. Essentially there is a DownloadFile.aspx?fileId=XXXX

Anyway I'm having issues getting the security right on the folder. Whenever i navigate to the page i get a login/password prompt from IIS asking for rights on the local computer. I need any internet user to be able to access a file (the application handles the security of who should be able to get to those files)

I tried adding Read to EVERYONE as well as adding it to the ASPNET user. No luck. I still get the prompt.

Any suggestions?

EDIT: Adding a bit of clarity. The ASPX file that is getting the security popup now is only calling a File.Exists on the UNC of the network share. This particular script isnt serving up the file for download (yet) and it still fails.

p.s. I'm aware this might not be the best way to serve these files. I'm a contractor doing work for a client who is migrating their site to another web host. We need to get it working before we can hopefully get in to rewrite this. Minimal impact is key.

Comment: 1 other issue i found not related to the question for anyone who finds this. The original app had custom security on the script in the web.config but the web.config was wrong. It had forms auth but the xml wasnt correct (needed mode="Forms") once added it redirected accordingly and w/ security setup right users can download the files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the file is on a different share, first of all you need to use the Response.WriteFile() method to actually send the file down.

Then from a permissions standpoint you simply need to have the ASPNET (or NETWORK SERVICE on Win 2003/Vista/Win 2008) with permissions to read/write as needed to that folder.

Comment: Going to flag this as the answer. I was using ASPNET i needed NETWORK SERVICE. There were other issues but this helped the most.

Answer (score 0):

Use the "Everyone" group with discretion. Check the security permission of the Virtual Dirsctory in IIS. Should only be "Anonymous". Try [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/david.wang/archive/2005/07/11/Allow_file_downloads_on_IIS_6.aspx) and then follow settings found [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/271071) to secure the server.

Answer (score 0):

If you are linking to the content directly, then the ASPNET user will not be involved. That user is only used for executing ASPx files in IIS. To allow a user on the web to access the file directly, ensure that the account "IUSR_*computerName* has access to the file.